# Is there a safeunlink syscall in Unix?

Tags: unix, filesystems, system-calls, unlink, inode

There is an `unlink` syscall in Unix, which takes a path as argument, and unlinks that path from inode.

Suppose this case. I will open a file, access the contents, and then decide that it should be unlinked. By this time, a different process has replaced that path with a different file for some reason. Now if I call unlink with that path, it will unlink the wrong file, and probably confusing the other process.

Hence, is there way where I can pass the inode number along with the path to `(safe)unlink` syscall so that it can atomically check if the path refers to the same inode and then unlink, if not report an errno or do a no-op?

Is there a way to do that in Unix? If not why is it left out? Is such a syscall not necessary for some reason? Can it be emulated using combination of other syscalls? Is it missed out by mistake?

Comment: Linux has `unlinkat()` but that's still not quite what you're looking for (I don't think you can pass an empty path).

Comment: @TobySpeight `unlinkat` is for relative paths right! I don't think that is useful in this case.

Comment: This argument is similar to why we needed `tgkill` when we already had `tkill`.

Comment: My comment was saying that I think the answer is "no, there's no such syscall".  POSIX doesn't have `unlinkat()`, so it almost certainly doesn't have what you want.  (BTW, a file-descriptor is probably a better choice than an inode number, as it carries the device number as well.)

Comment: As to why it's left out - such race conditions were not seen as a priority when the interface was codified - that's why `unlinkat()` came later and not on all systems.

Comment: @TobySpeight Don't the inode numbers for device files contain device id? What do you mean when you say file-descriptor carries device number as well?

Comment: No, inode numbers are unique only within a particular filesystem.  They couldn't be otherwise, since there's no way to guarantee any newly created inodes don't conflict with those on some device that's not yet mounted.

Comment: @TobySpeight [This](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode#POSIX_inode_description) article says that inode contains device id.

Comment: You've not read that properly.  A _block device_ or _character device_ filesystem entry has the id of the device it represents.  That's not the same (usually!) as the device of the filesystem which contains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no interface to `unlink()` functionality that avoids the race condition described here.

Filesystem operations in POSIX have always been at risk of name substitution; Linux added `openat()`, `unlinkat()` and more to mitigate these, but never added an interface that checks the final name matches an expected inode.

I don't think there's a way to get this atomic unlink-if-matching behaviour without adding to the syscall API, because anything we do from user-space here is subject to races.  The only possibility is if your target system supports mandatory access locks on directories, and has an equivalent of `unlinkat()`.

Comment: Initially they might have missed/depriortised it. But now, once they know they are lacking something, can't they add it?

Comment: Also, what is name substitution problem in POSIX?

Comment: Who is "they"?  If you want to add this functionality, why not implement it and post your patches for consideration?

Comment: I don't know yet how to do that. Though I will check that. By "they" I referred to the POSIX standards committee (i know such a thing exist for C++, not sure for POSIX) as this requires an API change.